# Match url with uppercase letters except if it contains a filename like .jpg,.css,.js etc

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx, regex-negation

I need a Regular Expression that can match url with uppercase letters but do not match if it contains a filename like .jpg,.css,.js etc

I want to redirect all uppercase url to lowercase but only when it is not pointing to a file resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regex visualizer like [regexpal.com](https://www.regexpal.com/).

Here's an example of a regular expression that approximates what you're trying to do:

```
\w+\.(?:com|net)(?:/[A-Z]+){1,}[/]?(?:\.jpg|\.png|\.JPG|\.PNG){0}$
```

- `\w+\.(?:com|net)` captures a domain of the form `word.com` or `word.net`. (You'll need to add other domains or improve this if you want to capture subdomains as well.)
- `(?:/[A-Z]+){1,}[/]?`captures all-caps directories like `/FOO/BAR/` with an optional trailing slash.
- `(?:\.jpg|\.png|\.JPG|\.PNG){0}$` captures exactly *zero* of the extensions listed; you'll obviously need to add to this list of extensions.

But perhaps rethink your routing; it's better form to keep all assets in devoted directories on your server, so that you can simply pass any request to `mysite.com/assets/` along unchanged while handling other URLs.

Comment: Actually i want to redirect :

https://example.com/poDcast/ to https://example.com/podcast/ 

But i do not want to redirect https://example.com/image/Abc.jpg to https://example.com/image/abc.jpg 

So the regex should match the URL when it have a uppercase letter but only when it does not end with a file like .jpg .css etc.

Comment: Change the `[A-Z]+` group to `\w+`.

Comment: \w+\.(?:com|net)(?:/\w+){1,}[/]?(?:\.jpg|\.png|\.JPG|\.PNG){0}$  will match https://example.net/abc  as well but i only want it to match when there is any capital letter